# Do While until variable is empty/null

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Not sure if this is possible:

```
                myString = 313233

                counter = Len(myString)                     

                Do while counter > 0

                position = 1

                take = 2

                response.write (" counter:" & counter)

                first_two = Mid(myString, position, take)

                response.write (" Each loop:" & first_two)                                              

                position = position + 2

                counter = counter - 2

                Loop
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please? or is this possible via different method?

The code above is running once and returning: 31 not 31 32 33

Thanks.

UPDATE: Realized my error shortly after but now position won't increment to give to move up the variable

Comment: `position` won't increment because you set it to `1` at the start of the loop. When it reaches the `Mid()` call it's always `1`. You should only initialise variables outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `position` variable to `1` at the start of the `Do` loop. As it stands whenever `Mid()` is called it is passed `position = 1` which will return `31`.

Fix this by moving it outside the loop so `position` can increment.

```
myString = 313233
counter = Len(myString)                     

'Set before start of loop
position = 1
take = 2

Do while counter > 0
  response.write (" counter:" & counter)
  first_two = Mid(myString, position, take)
  response.write (" Each loop:" & first_two)
  'Use take variable so increment is always the same.                                          
  position = position + take
  counter = counter - take
Loop
```

*<sup>Code untested</sup>*

Comment: Thanks - didn't even consider that.